# Windows 10 - Make Alt+Tab per App (like mac)

Tags: windows-10

On Windows, when we do Alt + Tab it cycles through all windows. Instead is it possible to make it cycle through apps?

And then Alt + ` can cycle through the windows of the current app?

Comment: If you want to be able to do this you would have to replace the Windows Explorer shell with an alternative shell

Answer (score 0):

You can use ctrl + tab to change current apps windows and use ctrl + shift + tab to make it reverse (you can user shift in Alt + tab too)

Comment: This isn't working for me. It is changing the tabs in my web browser.